# how to consume multiple context in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Is it possible to consume multiple context in one component which is from two different component . I tried It but but I am not getting value
This is the component which consume two different context

```js
import React from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../App";
import { NewContext } from "./CompY";

const CompX = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <UserContext.Consumer>
        {(user) => {
          return (
            <>
              <NewContext.Consumer>
                {(username) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <h1>Hello {user.username} </h1>
                      <h2>This is CompX in the {user.name} component</h2>
                      <h3>This is {username} </h3>
                    </>
                  );
                }}
              </NewContext.Consumer>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </UserContext.Consumer>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CompX;
```

Here is the App.Js

Comment: This article might be useful to you https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-context-api-with-hooks-efficiently-while-avoiding-performance-bottlenecks

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple contexts in `functional component` easily with `useContext`

`Consumer` and `provider` is bad practice in `functional component`

```
import { UserContext } from "../App";
import { NewContext } from "./CompY";

const CompX = () => {
    const user = useContext(UserContext);
    const newUser = useContext(NewContext);

    ....
}
```

Comment: Its not working   `code`<div>
      <h1>Hello {user.name} </h1>
      <h2>This is CompX in the {user.component} component</h2>
      <h3> This is {newUser} in the CompX component </h3>
    </div>

Comment: please check, its working code, look out https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!